# Docker starting extremely slow and recieve exceptions using docker compose

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, netflix-eureka

**Update**: It's working pretty fine when I am using a `network` and link them one by one and start them afterwards! It's just not working when using `docker-compose`.

I am using `eureka discovery service` and `zuul`. I got 4 microservices at all.
Once I start them they try to register themselves at then `eureka service` but they are failing doing that. While they try to register at the `eureka-service` they exceptions: `Request execution error` (see below).
After a while they register themselves in most of the cases but still keep throwing exceptions.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  eureka-service:
    image: eureka-service
    ports:
    - 8761:8761

  article-service:
    image: articlemicroservice
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    ports:
    - 8080:8080

  customer-service:
    image: customermicroservice
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    ports:
    - 8082:8082

  order-service:
    image: ordermicroservice
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    ports:
    - 8084:8084

  shop-service:
    image: shopmicroservice
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    ports:
    - 8083:8083

  gateway-service:
    image: gateway
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    ports:
    - 8090:8090

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    depends_on:
    - eureka-service
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: shop
      MYSQL_USER: shop
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: shop
    volumes:
    - mysqltest:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysqltest:
    driver: local
```

**eureka service**

`application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    #registerWithEureka: false
    #fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://192.168.99.100:8761/
```

**typical microservice application.yml**

`application.yml`

```
    server:
  port: 8082
eureka:
  client:
    #registerWithEureka: true
    #fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-service:8761/eureka/
```

**exceptions**

```
shop-service_1      | 2018-03-26 08:21:20.188  INFO 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SHOPMICROSERVICE/3a1143f7775d:shopmicroservice:8083: registering service...
shop-service_1      | 2018-03-26 08:21:28.235 ERROR 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error
shop-service_1      |
shop-service_1      | com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
shop-service_1      |   at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
shop-service_1      |   at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
shop-service_1      |   at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
shop-service_1      |   at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
shop-service_1      |   at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.register(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:829) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      | Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
shop-service_1      |   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:278) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:286) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:230) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
shop-service_1      |   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
shop-service_1      |   at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
shop-service_1      |   ... 29 common frames omitted
shop-service_1      |
shop-service_1      | 2018-03-26 08:21:28.260  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
shop-service_1      | 2018-03-26 08:21:28.264  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SHOPMICROSERVICE/3a1143f7775d:shopmicroservice:8083 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
shop-service_1      |
shop-service_1      | com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:829) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
shop-service_1      |   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
shop-service_1      |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing Eureka's application.yml to:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    ip-address: 127.0.0.1
  server:
    enable-self-preservation: false
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  serviceUrl:
    defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

Client portion, in my case, looks like this:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:9999/eureka/
instance:
  preferIpAddress: true
```

Another thing to keep in mind - even so you have 'depends_on:' in your docker compose file, Docker doesn't wait for service in that container to became actually available, so it's normal to see few exceptions from Eureka clients upon startup. If it's bothering you take a look at [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)